# Fetch data from multiple CSV to excel with header in single excel horizontally if computername is same then override row otherwise entry in second row

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

data in multiple CSV File which is in Vertically. Now my requirement is import multiple CSV File data in a single excel file horizontally. Also if having having same computername then override otherwise add data in next row.

CSV File data1:-

| ComputerName | Parameter | Version | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DDPC1 | Windows 11 | 20H2 | Compliant |
|  | Patching | NA | Compliant |

CSV File data2:-

| ComputerName | Parameter | Version | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DDPC2 | Windows 11 | 20H2 | Compliant |
|  | Patching | NA | Not-Compliant |

Trying to export CSV File data in horizontal format:-

| ComputerName | Windows 11 | Patching |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DDPC1 | Compliant | Compliant |
| DDPC2 | Compliant | Not-Compliant |

```
$path = "C:\script-$((get-date).tostring('dd-MM-yyyy')).csv"
$P = Import-Csv -Path "C:\kumar.csv" | select ComputerName, Parameter, Status |
  foreach {
            new-object psobject -Property @{
                                             ComputerName = $env:computername
                                             Parameter = $_.Parameter
                                             Status       = $_.Status
                                             }
           } | Select ComputerName, Parameter, Status |
               Export-Excel  $path -Force
```

Comment: What is your question here? Your post is just some code, and a couple of pictures; it doesn't explain what you're asking, or what isn't working about the attempt you have.

Comment: You need to provide some actual data and your desired result as well.

Comment: @Dennis Edited the question and shared the desired output. Also shared the data of 2 csv file which needs to be exported in single excel file horizontally.

Comment: And by "Excel" you mean text file using comma separated values (CSV) and not xls or xlsx?

Comment: @Larnu Can you check again. I have edited the question again.

Comment: @Dennis Can you check again. I have edited the question again.

Comment: You are missing the computer name in second row in both files.  Import CSV will not not fill in column.

Comment: @jdweng second row is blank because 1 CSV File contains 1 computer data. Please check export CSV File data.

Comment: Yes, but it is not simple to just do a join to the two tables.  You have to enumerate the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a table like this :

```
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\*.csv
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($csv in $csvFiles)
{
   $csvFile = Import-Csv -Path $csv
   $rowNumber = 0 
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   foreach($row in $csvFile)
   {
      $rowNumber += 1
      if($rowNumber -eq 1) { 
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ComputerName -NotePropertyValue $row.ComputerName 
      }
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $row.Parameter -NotePropertyValue  $row.Status
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks it working as expected. But I have Query. If i want to run this script on multiple system using batch file and fetch computername, date , time , user signin details in a single csv file horizontally then what changes we need to make.

Comment: Either you run script multiple times and append to same csv file or you add another outside loop with arrays of folders to get text file.

Comment: i want to run this script on multiple system using batch file. Please suggest. i'am new to powershell

Comment: You need to do design before writing code.  You are working with Windows which does not allow multiple systems to write to same file.  You also have issue that you inputs and outputs have different formats.  And you want to merge data to get a Total Count.   Just writing code does not solve a DESIGN issue.